# C# libraries for internationalization?

Tags: c#, internationalization

**What libraries are there to write C# internationalized applications?**

Typical functionalities that should be contained in the library:

- Validation of country specific data (e.g. VAT numbers, phone numbers, addresses,...)
- Validation of bank and financial coordinates (e.g. Credit Card numbers, IBAN,...)
- Language-specific functionalities (e.g. numbers to words to numbers, summarize,...)
- Language specific content filtering (e.g. swearword filtering...)

An example of such libraries in Perl would be the [Internationalization/Locale section](http://search.cpan.org/modlist/Internationalization_Locale) of CPAN.

What C# solutions are available?

---

Note: I am not looking for an introduction to the System.Globalization namespace :)

---

Note 2: Should I desume that there are no options available? Is someone interested in joining forces and create one?

---

Note 3: Edit to make the question appear on front page in hope of more answers. This isn't such a hard question, how is it possible that Stackers don't ever do i18n?

Comment: I guess i18n is a kind of taboo topic - everyone uses their own approach to solutions (and sometimes it takes the ugly form of creating entirely new sites for each language/culture/country).

Comment: The swearword filtering alone could employ teams of people for every region and language full time.

Comment: Interesting. I was just discussing the validation aspect of this problem with my colleague. Then I returned to my PC and 15 seconds later I'm seeing this question. :)

Answer (score 4):

One project that is working towards a database of globalization, internationalization and localization knowledge is the [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/), based on the old ICU project at IBM.

As it is a database of XML data it doesn't contain any .NET-specific code, but as a body of knowledge it is very good.

Only a smallish subset is in the .NET framework. Microsoft hasn't gone near any of the supplemental stuff, like postcode formats, number spelling (for check/cheque amounts), etc. Standard time zone names (from the [Olson/tz](ftp://elsie.nci.nih.gov/pub/) distribution), etc. are also included, with mappings to the Windows-specific names. Some of the hierarchical locale-specific behaviours also have better support.

Comment: Not only it is not a library, but most stuff is already in the .net stack.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say that no one does i18n, but I don't know of any generic tools that can be used for every project. Maintaining a database with all of the information you are looking for would be an epic project. It sounds like what you're looking for isn't a specific C# library, but more a collection of information online that you can draw from. If you were able to find a repository of swear words in various languages (for example), it would be trivial for you to use this in C#. I think that finding a solution that wraps up all of your requirements into an easy-to-use assembly is going to be impossible to find.

Comment: Example of things I would expect to see in the library: validation of phone numbers, address format, zip code, SSN (or equivalent), bank account numbers; name formatting; holidays calendar; a currency class; country specific classes, for example in UK you can derive an address from a postcode; etcetera...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at
http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/getwr/dotneti18n.mspx
and
http://www.dotneti18n.com/

Comment: I know System.Globalization quite well already. My question was different though. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

String to number and vice versa can be dones as following:

```
   culture = new CultureInfo(locale);
   int number = Convert.ToInt32(myString, culture.NumberFormat);
   string str= Convert.ToString(myNumber, culture.NumberFormat);
```

As to checking VATS and adresses, I'm interested in that too, haven't found anything useful so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a "library", per se, but I've actually ran into a great service (for pay), by a company called [E4X](http://www.fiftyone.com/) (former client of mine).
What they provide is complete localization of your ecommerce site, including language translations, currency exchanges, local billing and handling of financial transactions including region-specific taxes etc, and more. They even deal with logisitics of physical shipping...

Worth looking into, for an ecommerce business.  Let 'em know I sent you... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That's a huge endeavor. Let's start with one simple problem: phone numbers. Libphonenumber Google library at http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/ has a C# port at https://bitbucket.org/pmezard/libphonenumber-csharp with notes at http://blog.thekieners.com/2011/06/06/using-googles-libphonenumber-in-microsoft-net-with-c/. Appears to be a good library for handling both US and int'l numbers.